# Why is my ArrayList.remove(id) call not working?

Tags: java, debugging, arraylist

I have an ArrayList, which includes a number of items I want to remove.  I have the ids of the items to remove stored in another list.  Figured the following code should work trivially, but for some reason, the remove() calls are returning a false value:

```
  ArrayList<Integer> toRemove = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  ArrayList<JCheckBox> al = new ArrayList<JCheckBox>();

  /* Code that adds a bunch of items to al, and a few integers to toRemove */

  System.out.println("Size before removing: " + al.size());
  for (int i = toRemove.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    System.out.println("Removing id: " + toRemove.get(i) + ": ");
    System.out.println(al.get(toRemove.get(i)));
    System.out.println(al.remove(toRemove.get(i)));
  }
  System.out.println("Size after removing: " + al.size());
```

I'd get it if the get() call also returned a false value, but it does actually return the object in question.  What am I missing here?

The output of the code above:

```
Size before removing: 3
Removing id: 2: 
javax.swing.JCheckBox[...]
false
Size after removing: 3
```

Comment: Can you post exact declarations for 'al' and 'toRemove'?

Comment: Posted the definitions requested.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

My guess is you are having a problem with the fact that `remove()` is overloaded with both `int` and `Object`, while `get()` only takes an `int`. Try `remove(toRemove.get(i).intValue())`.

`remove(Object)` from `AbstractCollection` will search through the list and remove the given object, which won't be there because you are sending it an `Integer` and the list only has `JCheckBox`s. You are trying to call `remove(int)`, but because you are giving it an `Integer`, the Object overload is called instead. By converting the `Integer` to an `int`, you avoid this problem

Also, can you always be sure the Id in toRemove always equals the index? If toRemove is not in greatest to least order, it won't be.

Comment: Thanks - that worked!  And yeah, when I build toRemove, I'm sure it's in order, so that when I go over it in reverse order, I don't need to adjust the indexes as elements are removed.

Comment: This answer does not consider `NULL` objects

Comment: @Salman The question implies there are no `null`s. If there was a `null` then the line above the `remove()` call would throw a null pointer while unboxing the argument to the outer `get()` call.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your code.
First, the wrong "toRemove" method is getting invoked. When you call "toRemove.get(i)", the return value is autoboxed into a java.lang.Integer, instead of an int. Therefore, java.util.List#remove(Object) is called instead of java.util.List#remove(int). It's trying to remove an Integer object, and returns false.
If you cast the Integer to an int, the desired method will get invoked.

Second problem: each time you remove an element of the list, the indexes of all subsequent elements change, as those elements are "shifted" down. There are several ways to get around this. One is to sort your list of indexes in descending order. Another would be to use a set of indexes, create a new array, and copy into the new array only those elements whose index is not in the set.

Answer (score 0):

javax.swing.JCheckBox[...]?

Also, try remove elements by Objects value, like here:
http://www.easywayserver.com/blog/java-remove-element-in-arraylist/